# Understanding the conflict based search MAPF (cbs-mapf) package in Python

Tags: python, path-finding, pypi, maze, multi-agent

I am trying to use the pypi [cbs mapf package](https://pypi.org/project/cbs-mapf/) **which is a conflict based multi agent path finding algorithm**. It runs quite well for the example file [scenario1.yaml](https://github.com/GavinPHR/Multi-Agent-Path-Finding/blob/master/visualization/scenario1.yaml).

package installation:

```
pip install cbs-mapf
```

But when I try to write my own agent, gives me error.

my driver code:

```
from cbs_mapf.planner import Planner
planner=Planner(grid_size=1, robot_radius= 2, static_obstacles = [[0, 0], [19, 10]] )

print(planner.plan(starts=[[33, 16]],
    goals=[(54, 56)],
    debug=True))
```

Gives me an error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sayan/Documents/mapf cbs/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(planner.plan(starts=[[33, 16]],
  File "/home/sayan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cbs_mapf/planner.py", line 54, in plan
    solution = dict((agent, self.calculate_path(agent, constraints, None)) for agent in self.agents)
  File "/home/sayan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cbs_mapf/planner.py", line 54, in <genexpr>
    solution = dict((agent, self.calculate_path(agent, constraints, None)) for agent in self.agents)
  File "/home/sayan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cbs_mapf/planner.py", line 192, in calculate_path
    return self.st_planner.plan(agent.start, 
  File "/home/sayan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stastar/planner.py", line 85, in plan
    start = self.grid.snap_to_grid(np.array(start))
  File "/home/sayan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stastar/grid.py", line 49, in snap_to_grid
    return self.grid[i][j]
IndexError: index 15 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10
```

But when I change `static_obstacles= [[0, 0], [19, 10]]` to larger such as `static_obstacles= [[0, 0], [191, 107]]`, it works fine and gives me a plan.

> My question:

1. What is the issue with statistic obstacles being small? I could not make any sense out of the error message.
2. Also what does the grid parameter reflect actually. Size of each cell or the whole table?

Answer (score 0):

1. The issue with static obstacle being small is just that if you have state space very dense with obstacle the computation might be hard. The MAPF problem is NP-hard and the CBS solution might need to be exhaustive. (Intuitively, if there is a small number of obstacle, there are more potential leaves in the CBS Constraints Tree that are optimal.)
   Regarding the error you are seeing:
   For some reason in the mapf-cbs the size of the whole grid is defined by the obstacles. meaning that if you define `static_obstacles = [[0, 0], [19, 10]]` then the state space is a rectangle of size 19X10 and then your start and end states are out of bounds.
   Note that when you choose `static_obstacles= [[0, 0], [191, 107]]` indeed your start and gaol states are within this triangle.
   My guess is that the authors wanted you to explicitly define the border of the state space by explicitly defining the obstacles (as a frame or as two corners).
   See as an example [scenario2](https://github.com/GavinPHR/Multi-Agent-Path-Finding/blob/master/visualization/scenario2.yaml) where there are no obstacle inside the grid but the authors add "rectangle obstacle" as boundaries for the state space.
   It is not clear to me why the authors chose this design but at least it answers your question.
   Just to have a more complete answer, in order to see it in the code check the function `calculate_boundaries` where they define for instance `min_ = np.min(static_obstacles, axis=0)`, and use later this as boundary for the state space.
2. To your second question regarding the grid_size parameter.
   To my understanding from the code the grid size parameter defines the size of spatial steps that an agent can make, and the size of an obstacle. note that the agents' size can be larger (and hence they might collide even if they are in different locations).
   e.g. if you choose `grid_size = 2`, then your states space will be `[[1,1],[1,3],[3,1],...]`.

Comment: Ok this explanation helps, thanks a lot for the nitty-gritty details

Answer (score 0):

### In case you still have issues. Rather then understanding all details look for those .yaml files:
here is one:

GOAL:

- !!python/tuple [800, 100]
- !!python/tuple [800, 200]
- !!python/tuple [800, 300]
- !!python/tuple [800, 400]

GRID_SIZE: 50
RECT_OBSTACLES:
0:

- [0, 0]
- [1000, 800]
  1:
- [480, 450]
- [490, 460]
  ROBOT_RADIUS: 40
  START:
- !!python/tuple [50, 50]
- !!python/tuple [50, 150]
- !!python/tuple [50, 250]
- !!python/tuple [50, 550]